# emacs ( recompile -y )

Tags: emacs, elisp

Is it possible to pass a "-yes" flag to the 'recompile' command in emacs?

Excuse my complete lack of (e)lisp know-how. I got sick of going outside Emacs to compile my latex code, so i added the following key binding to my .emacs:

```
(global-set-key (kbd "<f12>") 'recompile);
```

Is it possible to automatically answer 'yes' to the following prompt that might appear: 
"A compilation process is running; kill it? (yes or no)."

Also, is it possible to make the window that opens and shows the output to scroll to the bottom automatically. The interesting stuff is typically down there. Maybe its possible to chain the following command after recompile: "C-x o, end-of-buffer".

Thanks!

Comment: Or maybe you could just pass `-halt-on-error` to `pdflatex` (or similar).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here's some code to solve your first problem (interrupting the current compilation):

```
(defun interrupt-and-recompile ()
  "Interrupt old compilation, if any, and recompile."
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors (kill-compilation))
  (recompile))
```

For your second problem (scrolling the compilation output), just customize the user setting [`compilation-scroll-output`](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/emacs/Compilation.html).

Answer (score 3):

This behaviour is governed by the `compilation-always-kill` global variable.  Customize it via `customize-variable` and set it to `t`.

Not sure which version of emacs first had this, but 26 and newer certainly does.

Comment: `NEWS.24` says it was added for Emacs 24.3.

Answer (score 2):

I somehow need to put kill-compilation into a ignore-errors with Emacs 23.2 to get it to work when no process is running. Otherwise works great.

```
(defun interrupt-and-recompile ()
  "Interrupt old compilation, if any, and recompile."
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors
    (kill-compilation))
  (recompile)
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Whenever I tried using `kill-compilation` with latex/pdflatex it did not work. I assume it is because latex does not respond to SIGINT.

Instead I am using the following hack, which first sets the `process-kill-without-query` bit of the `compilation`-buffer and then closes it (which kills the running process).

```
(defun interrupt-and-recompile ()
  "Interrupt old compilation, if any, and recompile."
  (interactive)
  (ignore-errors 
    (process-kill-without-query 
      (get-buffer-process
        (get-buffer "*compilation*"))))
  (ignore-errors 
    (kill-buffer "*compilation*"))
  (recompile)
)
```

Answer (score 0):

The other solutions didn't work for me for the same reason as sfeuz, but I didn't like the nuclear option of killing the hardcoded buffer by name.

Here's a short solution that autoanswers yes to that specific question by advising yes-or-no-p:

ftp://download.tuxfamily.org/user42/compilation-always-kill.el

(source: http://www.emacswiki.org/CompilationMode)